# I want to define a function that returns True if ALL the letters in a given word are present in a given list. And returns False, otherwise

Tags: python-2.7

I want this code in python. It is for an assignment.
BTW, I am a beginner in python so try not to use functions I might not know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried using for and while loop by using string slicing and list slicing. But that dosent work. I'll tell how: def isWordGuessed(word,list): for i in range(Len(word)): for n in range(Len(list)): if word[i]== list[n]: return True else: return False (Forgive me I couldn't make the right indentations because I'm using Mobile. But, there no problem with my indentation in the real code :))

Answer (score 0):

You leave your function right after the first iteration in both `for`-loops without even coming to the second letter.

`def isWordGuessed(word,list):
    for i in word:
        if i not in list:
            return False
    return True`

PS. `len` should not be capitalized.

Comment: That did it . Thanks!

Comment: Approve the correction I made to your question, so everyone can see your code correctly formatted and mark the question as answered if your problem was solved.